# Android : custom Drawable for the layout background . Child items are not clear?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My layout file is like this :

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="282dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="20dp"
        android:layout_y="208dp"
        android:alpha="155"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="155"
            android:hint="@string/hintUsername"
            android:padding="2dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="155"
            android:hint="@string/hintPassword"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butBrowse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="255"
            android:text="@string/but_browse" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And I set a custom Drawable to the layout programatically as follows :

```
ViewGroup layoutView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.login_layout, null); // (ViewGroup)
        layoutView.setBackground(new CustomDrawable(this) {
        });

private class CustomDrawable extends Drawable {

    private Context ctx;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public CustomDrawable(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
     //draw dynamic stuff to the 'bitmap'   
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        Paint p = new Paint();
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.bitmap,0,0,p);

        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return 15;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {

    }

}
```

Now my login_layout looks like this:

[image]

As can be seen in the picture , my child elements (edittext,password area, button) are not clearly visible.

[image]

My questions :

1.How to achieve something like above ?Do I have to apply another Drawable to the inner 'LinearLayout' ?

2.Is it possible to change the alpha level of the Textfields,Button so that it is more visible ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the opacity for your custom drawable which is currently set to 15. Increasing the opacity will make it more visible.

```
    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return 15; // increase this value
    }
```

Comment: changed to 255 and still the same